# Conversion of if condition to ternary operator

Tags: c, if-statement, ternary-operator

```
status = (Hcill_state == HCILL_STATE_AWAKE)?GPIO_Request(GPIO_5,13):API_FAIL;
```

Is the above code equivalent to the code below?

```
 if (Hcill_state == HCILL_STATE_AWAKE)
 {
     status = GPIO_Request (GPIO_5,13);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The two pieces of code are not equivalent, because the first one performs reassignment unconditionally, while the second one assigns only when the condition is true.

The equivalent of the first code would have an `else` branch assigning `API_FAIL` to `status`:

```
if (Hcill_state == HCILL_STATE_AWAKE)
{
    status = GPIO_Request (GPIO_5,13);
}
else
{
    status = API_FAIL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since, Ternary operator define as :

```
Condition ? if true : if false
```

In your second case you have an operation for `true` but not for `false`.

So, these code are not equal because in second one you do not have else statement.
It will be equal if you wrote second one like this.

```
if (Hcill_state == HCILL_STATE_AWAKE)
{
 status = GPIO_Request (GPIO_5,13);
}
else
{
 status = API_FAIL;
}
```